# missing /usr/include/sys

Tags: directory

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 under VMware running on a Windows 8 system.  I was looking for the file `include/sys/syscall.h` and noticed that the `include/sys` directory does not exist.  I tried reinstalling `linux-libc-dev` and `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` but the `include/sys` directory still isn't there.  How do I install this directory?  I know `syscall.h` is in the `bits` directory but there are other files in `include/sys` I use often I need.

Comment: Mine is provided by `libc6-dev-amd64` (64bit) or check for `libc6-dev`